# Unable to access fsx shared volume after ubuntu 18.04 reboot

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, amazon-fsx

Previously, I had a fsx volume mounted on /shared directory.
However, Ubuntu 18.04 + fsx has some bug which causes reboot of the instance to unmount the fsx volume

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution:

Mount the fsx volume again

```
wget -O - https://fsx-lustre-client-repo-public-keys.s3.amazonaws.com/fsx-ubuntu-public-key.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo bash -c 'echo "deb https://fsx-lustre-client-repo.s3.amazonaws.com/ubuntu bionic main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/fsxlustreclientrepo.list'
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt install -y lustre-client-modules-$(uname -r)
sudo mount -t lustre -o noatime,flock fs-<id of the fsx>.fsx.us-east-1.amazonaws.com@tcp:/fsx /shared
ubuntu@<>:~$ ls /shared/
DeepLearningExamples  checkpoint  checkpoints  checkpoints-1.data-00000-of-00001  checkpoints-1.index  conda_tf25  conda_tf25_hvd  deep-learning-models  nccl_hosts
```

However, cleaner solution would not require this re-mounting of fsx volume after instance reboot.